# How can I switch textures mid buffer?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures

I am loading high res images and drawing them to quad surfaces usually i switch the texture using glunifom, how ever the textures will change continually my data is packed with many quads in one buffer currently.

Can i do something like texture_id, vertex_data, uniform_data, texture_id, vertex_data, uniform_data and switch using the value as an attribute instead of a uniform or should i split this up into small buffers each with its own texture.

I dont know the texture in advance because these are loaded by the user and the quads are created on the fly with these textures so i am looking for best approach really to handle this.

I am after a method I can use with opengl and opengl-es.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without slightly more info - is there a fixed number of textures that any individual draw call will use, or is it limitless?  How exactly do the individual quads 'know' which texture they should sample?

Comment: well the idea is to allow the user to load in the textures, i can resize them to make them the correct size, but if i pack the data as above  texture_id, vertex_data, uniform_data each time a new image is loaded i can add texture_id, vertex_data, uniform_data. I asked around on G+ and was told its not possible via attribute arrays it sounds like in newer opengl there are exture arrays but those are not in opengl es.

Comment: I use texture arrays in gles 2.0 in my shaders, works just fine. Regardless, you would not need a true texture array, you could just use several non-array textures, and use conditionals to determine which to sample.